# how do I subtract single textbox values with multiple textboxes values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, subtraction

i have code but problem is that i can result from when i subtract total textbox value and advance textbox value  which is equals to  balance textbox. But after getting subtracted values into `balance textbox` then function cannot be `subtract balance textbox values with discount textbox value`?

when i subtracted total-advance and values showing in the balance textbox but problem is that i can't subtract balance textbox values with discount textbox value?

i want like this

Total-Advance=Balance-Discount?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getObj(objID){
return document.getElementById(objID);
}
function C(){
getObj("balance").value=parseFloat(getObj("total").value)-
(parseFloat(getObj("advance").value)) ;
return false;
}  

function D(){
getObj("balance").value=parseFloat(getObj("balance").value)-
(parseFloat(getObj("discount").value)) ;
return false;
}
</script> 

<input type="text" name="total" id="total" />
<input type="text" name="advance" id="advance" />
<input type="text" name="balance" id="balance"
 onfocus="return C();return D();" />
<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount" />
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It is difficult to understand what you are looking for. What do you need to calc? The balance?
Which are the formulas you would like to apply?
Balance = Total - Advance.
Balance = Balance - Discount

Comment: @pdjota when i subtracted total-advance and values showing in the balance textbox but problem is that i can't subtract balance textbox values with discount textbox value?

Comment: @pdjota Total-Advance=Balance-Discount?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Edit** : add `|| 0` to prevent NaN

```
<input type="text" name="balance" id="balance" onfocus="return C();" />

function C(){
  var balanceValue = parseFloat(getObj("total").value || 0)-
  (parseFloat(getObj("advance").value || 0)) ;

  getObj("balance").value  = parseFloat(balanceValue || 0) -
  (parseFloat(getObj("discount").value || 0)) ;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: its because when you dont have value so you can set `0` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You need to use || 0 when NaN

```
getObj = function (objID){
return document.getElementById(objID);
}
C = function () {
getObj("balance").value=parseFloat(getObj("total").value  || 0)-
(parseFloat(getObj("advance").value || 0)) ;
return false;
}  

D = function () {
getObj("balance").value=parseFloat(getObj("balance").value || 0)-
(parseFloat(getObj("discount").value)||0) ;
return false;
}
```

See an interactive example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdejuan/FcTd9/

Comment: Ok, then please mark the question as answered in any answer :)

Comment: i don't have so much reptution if you mark my question then i will get some reptution